# how can i store string value into textbox using c#

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, textbox

Here is my code, I can't figure out how to store gender value in `textbox.text`

```
string gender;
if (radio_male.Checked)
{
    gender = "Male";
}
if (radio_female.Checked)
{
    gender = "Female";
}
txtfirstname.Text = gender;
```

Comment: i think `txtfirstname.Text` is for name , so you placing `gender` in wrong textbox, else you code if fine

Answer (score 4):

`gender` is uninitialized. You can use [`?:`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) operator to reduce your code.

```
string gender = radio_female.Checked ? "Female" : (radio_male.Checked ? "Male" : string.Empty);
txtfirstname.Text = gender;
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to nest ?: operators?

Comment: Yes, but other way around. Code updated. It has same effect as the code of OP, with uninitialized error removed.

Comment: @tilak your code is working for me thanks for helping can you tell me that why my code is not working why the error is only i feel at txtbox.text=gender; how can i solve this problem through my code

Comment: change First line from `string gender;` to `string gender = string.Empty;`

Answer (score 3):

I guess you get a compiler error that `gender` may be unitialized. You can solve it by setting an empty string as a default:

```
string gender;
if (radio_male.Checked)
{
    gender = "Male";
}
else if (radio_female.Checked)
{
    gender = "Female";
}
else
{
    gender = ""; // or gender = string.Empty;
}
txtfirstname.Text = gender;
```

You're filling `txtfirstname` correctly. (apart from the fact it should maybe rather be `txtGender`, should it not?)

The actual problem is different: You cannot use a local variable without assigning a value to it. The C# compiler does not allow this (unlike C for example, as far as I know) to prevent you from getting weird errors at runtime.

Fields are initialized with `null` (value types with their default value) by default.

Comment: Or initialize gender to string.Empty

Comment: @m-y As far as I know, even `null` must be assigned explicitly to a local variable. Fields are initialized with `null` by default.

Comment: @Madu: I realized right after I typed that that it wasn't defaulted to null, so I deleted my comment. :)

Comment: or instead of the else, you can just initialize `string gender = ""` in the first place...

Comment: @m-y Alright, thanks for pointing out anyway. Added this bit of information to the post.

Answer (score 1):

```
string gender = radio_male.Checked? "Male" : "Female";
txtGender.Text = gender
```

I'm guessing thats your text box name..

Comment: Neatly short, but keep in mind that checking neither `radio_male` nor `radio_female` defaults to "female" in this code...

Answer (score 0):

```
string gender = "";
if (radio_male.Checked)
{
    gender = "Male";
}
else if (radio_female.Checked)
{
    gender = "Female";
}
txtfirstname.Text = gender;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try after initializing the variable gender as string.Empty.

Comment: This might be put in comment, instead of answer